# Why gridline not aligned inside gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new in ASP.NET, now I have to create a user control where I have to use `<asp:gridview>` with in gridview. That I did perfectly, but it's not shown properly aligned as like parent gridview column.

I don't know how can i do ,if anyone has an idea please share it with me .

To get a better idea about the issue please go with attached image file.

[image]

Image will help you to understand actual scenario.

Comment: Have you seen in other browser?

Comment: Do you have set the width of columns? the grid view auto arrange the columns, so the inside grid view will never be the same size as the parent

Comment: yes,i set ItemStyle-Width="90px" property in each column in both grid view

Comment: also set ControlStyle-Width="90px"